# Joomla error after uploading

Tags: php, joomla

just copied my joomla site folder to godaddy domain and when i visit the home page i get this error 
Fatal error: Call to a member function getDefault() on a non-object in /home/content/88/8216088/html/public_html/includes/router.php on line 123

any help ?

Comment: whatever's trying to call getDefault() on line 123 is not an object, obviously. Perhaps you should show some code.

Comment: What's the version of Joomla you're trying to use?

Comment: I know that it is because it is not an object but these are the joomla files not mine and they worked before ... i am using 1.5

Answer (score 1):

After some Googling, I've found a similar thread at http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?p=2441892. Since this sounds like a bug, I don't really think we will be able to solve it here.

The **best thing you can do now** is to try to help Joomla! developers with reporting the issue and following their instructions for debugging and solving it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ... I did as said but still same error